# Ways to transmit data from client to server (silently)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, client-server

I am kind of new to JavaScript / jQuery and Web Development. My current project is to build a small chat room for a website. Everything works, but I have one question:

How to transmit date from the client to the server and back (e.g. via javascript) (e.g. when some chat member sends a message)?

Of course I have implemented a solution that works: I use `$.get(...)` or `$(...).load(...)` to transmit data. Of course, every query is listed in the network section of the browser inspector. But when you open the inspector on 'big' sites, e.g. Facebook, no network activity is listed although I am sending/liking/clicking, which all has to be send to the server and be processed.

**So how the hack do these sites transmit data??**

Another problem: **How does the client receive information from the server (e.g. if some other chat member has send a new message)?** Currently I run a time interval that checks every 2 seconds for new messages.

Comment: search Websockets.

Comment: Take care to spell JavaScript correctly to avoid search collisions with Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is going to be a big refactoring, but you should read https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications